# Creating another loop and run it in parallel threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is my first week to parallel programming, and I can't seem to figure this out. When I debug the program, it's stuck at "Generating numbers...". I think the only way to fix this problem is by creating another loop for myself and run it in parallel threads. Can you please help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

const int NSIZE = INT_MAX / 5;

void gen_numbers (float numbers[], int how_many);
float gen_rand(int min, int max);
float sum(float array[], int num_elements);


float numbers[NSIZE];

int main()
{
    unsigned int seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    __int64 start1 = GetTickCount();

    cout << "Generating numbers..." << flush;
    gen_numbers(numbers, NSIZE);
    cout << "done." << endl;

    cout << "Summing the numbers..." << flush;
    float answer = sum(numbers, NSIZE);
    cout << "done" << endl;
    __int64 end1 = GetTickCount();

    cout << "Total time: " << end1 - start1 << endl;

    cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

float sum(float array[], int num_elements)
{
    float nsum = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:nsum)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        nsum += array[i];
    }
    return nsum;
}

void gen_numbers(float numbers[], int how_many)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = gen_rand(0, 10);
    }
}

float gen_rand(int min, int max)
{
    return(min + static_cast <float> (rand()) /
        (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (max - min))));
}
```

Comment: `rand()` is not thread-safe, I think you should use `rand_r()`

Answer (score -1):

To debug your program you may use `cout` after each expression.
So you will know where you stop and what data is at each step.

Comment: @takendarkk He already use it and that does not help because of parallel threads. Read carefully question: `When I debug the program, it's stuck at ...`